# Mongodb replicas have different data

Tags: mongodb

I have upgraded mongodb from 2.4 to 2.6 (first step to upgrade 3.0). Everything looks fine but when i check some collections and get count() I encounter different values. Here are some informations about my mongodb replicas.

rs.status()

```
{
"set" : "MongoCls",
"date" : ISODate("2015-07-02T13:11:31Z"),
"myState" : 1,
"members" : [
    {
        "_id" : 0,
        "name" : "mongo-db1.mydomain.com:myport",
        "health" : 1,
        "state" : 2,
        "stateStr" : "SECONDARY",
        "uptime" : 18430,
        "optime" : Timestamp(1435842673, 3),
        "optimeDate" : ISODate("2015-07-02T13:11:13Z"),
        "lastHeartbeat" : ISODate("2015-07-02T13:11:30Z"),
        "lastHeartbeatRecv" : ISODate("2015-07-02T13:11:30Z"),
        "pingMs" : 0,
        "syncingTo" : "mongo-db2.mydomain.com:27017"
    },
    {
        "_id" : 1,
        "name" : "mongo-db2.mydomain.com:myport",
        "health" : 1,
        "state" : 1,
        "stateStr" : "PRIMARY",
        "uptime" : 18431,
        "optime" : Timestamp(1435842673, 3),
        "optimeDate" : ISODate("2015-07-02T13:11:13Z"),
        "electionTime" : Timestamp(1435824275, 1),
        "electionDate" : ISODate("2015-07-02T08:04:35Z"),
        "self" : true
    },
    {
        "_id" : 2,
        "name" : "mongo-db3.mydomain.com:myport",
        "health" : 1,
        "state" : 2,
        "stateStr" : "SECONDARY",
        "uptime" : 18430,
        "optime" : Timestamp(1435842673, 3),
        "optimeDate" : ISODate("2015-07-02T13:11:13Z"),
        "lastHeartbeat" : ISODate("2015-07-02T13:11:31Z"),
        "lastHeartbeatRecv" : ISODate("2015-07-02T13:11:29Z"),
        "pingMs" : 0,
        "syncingTo" : "mongo-db2.mydomain.com:myport"
    },
    {
        "_id" : 3,
        "name" : "mongo-db-arbiter.mydomain.com:myport",
        "health" : 1,
        "state" : 7,
        "stateStr" : "ARBITER",
        "uptime" : 18430,
        "lastHeartbeat" : ISODate("2015-07-02T13:11:30Z"),
        "lastHeartbeatRecv" : ISODate("2015-07-02T13:11:31Z"),
        "pingMs" : 0
    }
],
"ok" : 1
```

}

In the primary replica, rs.printReplicationInfo()

```
configured oplog size:   5120MB
log length start to end: 14131222secs (3925.34hrs)
oplog first event time:  Tue Jan 20 2015 01:55:51 GMT+XXXX (XXX)
oplog last event time:   Thu Jul 02 2015 16:16:13 GMT+XXX (XXX)
now:                     Thu Jul 02 2015 16:16:54 GMT+XXX (XXX)
```

In one of the secondary replica rs.printSlaveReplicationInfo()

```
source: mongo-db1.mydomian.com:myport
    syncedTo: Thu Jul 02 2015 16:17:13 GMT+XXX (XXX)
    0 secs (0 hrs) behind the primary 
source: mongo-db3.mydomain.com:myport
    syncedTo: Thu Jul 02 2015 16:17:13 GMT+XXX (XXX)
    0 secs (0 hrs) behind the primary
```

In the other secondary replica, rs.printSlaveReplicationInfo()

```
source: mongo-db1.mydomain.com:myport
    syncedTo: Thu Jul 02 2015 16:19:13 GMT+XXX (XXX)
    0 secs (0 hrs) behind the primary 
source: mongo-db3.mydomain.com:myport
    syncedTo: Thu Jul 02 2015 16:19:13 GMT+XXX (XXX)
    0 secs (0 hrs) behind the primary
```

Everything looks fine but when i try to count on a collection, i get different results. Secondary replicas have the same result but primary replica has a different result.

What may cause this? Is there a way to force sync replicas except initial sync? Do you have any suggestions or ideas to resolve this issue?

edit: The collections I'm checking are not active collections. I mean there are no inserts, deletes or updates in the time being.